# java subclass question

Tags: java, inheritance, tree, subclass

I have a `BinarySearchTree` class which is built using a `BinaryTree` class. Now I want to build a `RedBlackTree` class by subclassing the `BinarySearchTree` class. The problem is that the `BinaryTree` class doesn't have a field for color. So, I created a `ColorBinaryTree` class that's a subclass of the `BinaryTree` class. Here's where I get a little confused. In my BinaryTree class I have the following method

```
protected BinaryTree<E> parent(){
     return parent;
}
```

where parent is obviously another `BinaryTree`. In my `RedBlackTree` class, I will need to be able to access parents of `ColorBinaryTree` objects as well. However, I can't just use the method inherited from the `BinaryTree` class because that returns a `BinaryTree` object which means I can't access the color. With the following code I get an error

```
ColorBinaryTree<E> parent = newNode.parent();
```

where `newNode` is a `ColorBinaryTree` object. So it seems to me the only way to do it is to overwrite the above method in my `ColorBinaryTree` sublcass like so.

```
@Override 
protected ColorBinaryTree<E> parent(){
     return parent;
}
```

Am I missing some way to get aorund this or do I just have to go and override all of the methods that return BinaryTree objects? If so it seems kind of a waste since the body of the methods are exactly the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a reason you're not casting the result of the superclass's parent function?

Like this:

```
ColorBinaryTree<E> parent = (ColorBinaryTree<E>)newNode.parent();
```

Also kind of a pain, but probably what you're looking for.

The best way to deal with it, is to probably override all of the functions from your base class returning BinaryTree with a method that returns ColorBinaryTree.  Then in the implementation of the child class call the parent's method and perform the cast there before returning.  That way you don't have a million casts spread out in your code.  It might look like this:

```
@Override
protected ColorBinaryTree<E> parent() {
    return (ColorBinaryTree<E>)super.parent();
}
```

Comment: You can, but it's not as type-safe as doing the covariant overrides. i.e., the covariant overrides guarantee that `ColorBinaryTree.parent()` always returns `ColorBinaryTree`, never just a plain `BinaryTree`.

Comment: "Covariant override" is a new term to me.  Are you suggesting he rewrite the body of each of his methods?  That's obscene and ridiculous and I'll take the lack of type safety.  Doing that completely beats the point of a class heirarchy.  If, on the other hand, you are simply suggesting he override all the methods returning the `BinaryTree` in the parent class with methods returning `ColorBinaryTree` in the child class and perform the cast in there, then yes, I agree with you.

Comment: The cast as you had it in your edit is just fine---it's just an implementation detail and doesn't burden the caller with having to figure out if the cast is safe.

Comment: @Chris Yeah, definitely.  Not to mention it can potentially save a lot of key strokes.  I just had never heard "covariant override" before.  No matter how I try I can't keep up with all the terminology.  It seems everything has to have a name...

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you should do the covariant overrides. This is not "a waste", since it constrains the return type of `parent` for all subclasses of `ColorBinaryTree`.

Comment: what if I have a method that has an input of BinaryTree type. Should I  override those as well and change the input type to ColorBinaryTree?

Comment: @jhlu87 Yeah, probably.  That will ensure that someone doesn't actually send in a BinaryTree where a ColorBinaryTree is expected.  It'll help you catch that sort of error a lot sooner -- at the source of the problem rather than down the line when it explodes at not having the color field.

Comment: +1 to using covariant overrides - they fit this scenario perfectly. Much better than typecasting.